# Problem with "in" a system query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, query-performance

I have this query and I want get the **top 5** of `force_matching_signature`.
After that I want to display additional information for each of the sub results.

The following query works fine when the `IN` statement returns only one result (`first 1`) and in the main `SELECT` I use an equal sign, but if I want to return more than one row within the CTE portion and I put `in` in main query the query **never** ends.

```
WITH
    top_signature
    AS
        (   SELECT force_matching_signature, COUNT (*) "Count"
            FROM gv$sqlarea
            WHERE force_matching_signature <> 0
            GROUP BY force_matching_signature
            ORDER BY 2 DESC
            FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY)
  SELECT force_matching_signature,
         module,
         users_executing,
         COUNT (*)     CUANTOS
    FROM gv$sqlarea
   WHERE force_matching_signature IN 
       (
       SELECT force_matching_signature FROM top_signature
       )
GROUP BY force_matching_signature, module, users_executing
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

I can't think of how I could optimize the statement so that it takes a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Have you tried `INNER JOIN`ing `force_matching_signature` to `top_signature` instead of using an `IN` clause?... generally speaking that should be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one - it seemed snappy on most databases I've tried it on

```
WITH
    top_signature
    AS
        (   SELECT /*+ materialize */ force_matching_signature, COUNT (*) "Count"
            FROM gv$sqlarea
            WHERE force_matching_signature <> 0
            GROUP BY force_matching_signature
            ORDER BY 2 DESC
            FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY)
  SELECT g.force_matching_signature,
         g.module,
         g.users_executing,
         COUNT (*)     CUANTOS
    FROM gv$sqlarea g, top_signature t
   WHERE g.force_matching_signature = t.force_matching_signature
GROUP BY g.force_matching_signature, g.module, g.users_executing
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```